# Adding drag feature to select multiple( range) of dates from calendar using CLNDR.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I am making a calendar using [CLNDR.js lib](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR), its working good for selecting one date, but now we want to select range of dates by dragging on calendar boxes (dates).

[image]

As you can see in the image there are two handle's through which the user can drag, there is jquery-ui draggable but can anyone demonstrate or guide me through this as to how i can acheive this functionality or if its possible through CLNDR.js itself.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: #ZainNazirButt You ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @StephenMcDowell yes, i used the jquery drag and drop feature for this. Making the handles draggable and the boxes drop-able. So you can free move the handles and apply a class to the box on which handle crosses and at the end when the selection is complete you check for all the boxes between the two handles by checking that class you previously applied and applying another class that maybe highlights the selected boxes. I can post some code reference for this in the answer if you want. I'll have to look it up though.

Comment: If its not too much trouble I think posting your solution would help me (and the community).  Note the request for native support has also been opened. https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/issues/336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i achieved this by using the jquery drag and drop. Whenever one of the box is clicked i added a certain class to it and added the drag handlers. Then making the boxes droppable to drop handles on them. If you are unfimiliar with jQuery drag and drop please have a [look](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). I have removed some details that are specific to my project. What i have shared here is mainly the core things used for this drag feature, except for some specific functions you will see. I hope this helps.

```
// highlighting the box
   $(this).addClass("bg-white");

// adding drag handlers to the date box
  $(this).append('<div id="dragable-icons" ><span class="pull-left drag-icon" id="left-icon" style="z-index: 999; left:-8px" >' +
                '<i class="fa fa-arrows " aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="pull-right drag-icon" id="right-icon" style="z-index: 999; right:-8px">' +
                '<i class="fa fa-arrows" aria-hidden="true" ></i>' +
                '</span></div>')

 // making the icons draggable
            $("#left-icon , #right-icon").draggable({
                containment: ".calendar-rows", scroll: true
            });

 // all the boxes with class '.active' will be droppable (i.e box with 'active' class will be selected by dragging the icons on it)
            $(".day-active").droppable({
                accept: " #right-icon, #left-icon",
                over: function (event, ui) { // when the handle is over a box
                    if($(this).hasClass("day-unavailable")){
                            $(this).removeClass("day-unavailable");
                            $(this).addClass("prev-unavailable");
                        }
                    $(this).addClass("bg-white");
                },
                // drop: when icons dragging icons are dropped on some date box
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    // if left icon moved then update startDateBox  otherwise endDatebox (calculations)

                    if ($(event.toElement.parentElement).hasClass("pull-left")) {
                        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 25,left: -7}).appendTo(this);
                        startDateBox = $(this)
                    }
                    else {
                        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top: 25,left: 7}).appendTo(this);
                        endDateBox = $(this)
                    }

                    $('.calendar-rows').find(".bg-white").removeClass("bg-white");
                    $(startDateBox).addClass("bg-white");
                    $(endDateBox).addClass("bg-white");
                    // get all selected boxes
                    datebox = $(".bg-white")
                    len = datebox.length
                    // generateDate(), getDates(), setDateModify() : notes at end of file
                    // selecting all dates between startDate and endDate
                    startdate = generateDate(datebox[0])
                    enddate = generateDate(datebox[len - 1])
                    var dateArray = getDates(new Date(startdate), (new Date(enddate)));
                    var length = dateArray.length;
                    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                        if (parseInt(dateArray[i].getMonth() + 1) > 9) {
                            month = (parseInt(dateArray[i].getMonth()) + 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            month = "0" + (parseInt(dateArray[i].getMonth()) + 1);
                        }
                        if (dateArray[i].getDate() > 9) {
                            date = dateArray[i].getDate()
                        }
                        else {
                            date = "0" + dateArray[i].getDate()
                        }
                        date = dateArray[i].getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + date
                        var class_name = ".calendar-day-" + date
                        if ($(class_name).hasClass("day-unavailable")) {
                                $(class_name).removeClass("day-unavailable");
                                $(class_name).addClass("prev-unavailable");
                            }  
                        $(class_name).addClass("bg-white");

                    }
                    setDateModify(startdate, enddate)
                }
            });
```